# How to disable HTTP Methods on cowboy server

Tags: cowboy

i need help on how to disable HTTP methods on my cowboy server.

Tried to search on the internet but eneded up with no solutions

Comment: Me too!  OPTIONS is being flagged as a vuln.  Can't find out how to disable it

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation for `method`](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/0d0e7d164c72799b48275c0c79a7a9d5c08e652e/doc/src/manual/cowboy_req.method.asciidoc) gives this example:

```
init(Req, State) ->
    case lists:member(cowboy_req:method(Req), [<<"GET">>, <<"POST">>]) of
        true -> handle(Req, State);
        false -> method_not_allowed(Req, State)
    end.
```

You can easily adapt that to be a blacklist instead of a whitelist. For example, to ban `OPTIONS` and `TRACE`, you'd do this:

```
init(Req, State) ->
    case lists:member(cowboy_req:method(Req), [<<"OPTIONS">>, <<"TRACE">>]) of
        false -> handle(Req, State);
        true -> method_not_allowed(Req, State)
    end.
```

Comment: Awesome.  Now I just have no idea if RabbitMQ exposes anything related in their use of it.